# Invalid block tag on line 66: 'endblock', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django

Why is it giving me this strange error: Did you forget to register or load this tag? it was working fine but when i did some changes in this code it started this error... i was going through question related to this issue but could not find the solution....

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pagination">
    {% for item in post.object_list %}
<!--     {% for item in post %}-->
          <div class="card my-3 text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">

            <img src="/media/{{item.thumbnail}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{item.intro}}</p>
<!--                href={% url 'bicep' %}-->
              <a href="blog_detail/{{item.post_id}}" class="btn btn-primary">read more...</a>

<!--                <a href="{% url 'blog_detail/pk' pk=item.post_id %}" class="btn btn-primary">read more...</a>-->
            </div>
          </div>

    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: So, which is "Line 66"?

Comment: Also, Django doesn't care about html comments. So this code: `<!--     {% for item in post %}-->` **will run**. If you want to comment out django's template code, use the [`comment`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#comment) tag. I assume this is what's causing the error.

Comment: {% endblock %} this is on line 66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django disregards HTML comments. That means django **will run** this code:

```
<!--     {% for item in post %}-->
```

This is what's causing the error because django is expecting an `endfor` closing tag for this loop.

Either remove this line from your code or use django's [`comment`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#comment) template tag to comment out the template related code:

```
{% comment %}
     {% for item in post %}
{% endcomment %}
```